# Concat string into file

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a file with the following content (I placed 3 lines for example):

```
12743002785468    |MOVIL APPLE IPHONE4 16GB BLANCO         |NVEN          |Centro de Atención  VIP            |0862034032
12747002147595    |MOVIL APPLE IPHONE4 16GB BLANCO         |NVEN          |Centro de Atención  VIP            |0862033996
```

I have a variable date (20140430) I want to concatenate the beginning of each record like this:

```
20140430|12743002785468    |MOVIL APPLE IPHONE4 16GB BLANCO         |NVEN          |Centro de Atención  VIP            |0862034032
20140430|12747002147595    |MOVIL APPLE IPHONE4 16GB BLANCO         |NVEN          |Centro de Atención  VIP            |0862033996
```

I tried to use this:

```
cat /home/file.txt | awk '{print "'"20140430"'""|"$0;}' > /home/file.txt
```

and

```
sed -i 's/^/20140430|/' /home/file.txt > /home/file.txt
```

But not work and i could not do that to my file of 180,000 records. Anyone have another idea how I can concatenate? The operating system is SunOS 5.11 sun4v sparc sun4v 11.1
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: This is because you are redirecting to the same file. The commands are fine, just redirect to another file and it will be fine. Also, `sed -i` alone does in-place replacement, so don't redirect.

Comment: Those commands should have clobbered the contents of that file entirely.

Comment: Sorry, i tried to redirect to other file, example file.tmp but not work neither

Comment: Check the contents of the file, as @EtanReisner said, the commands you ran (if exactly as stated) will have overwritten `/home/file.txt` entirely.

Comment: If those aren't the commands you actually ran then you need to give us the commands you did and check the contents of the source file and give us the output that you actually get from the commands you actually ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also loop and append:

```
while read line; do
   echo 20140430'|'$line
done < /home/file.txt > /home/file.txt.tmp
mv file.txt.tmp file.txt
```

Comment: Excellent my friend worked in the best way. Thank you a lot!